# How to have a dialog with a design from xml?

Tags: android, xml, dialog

What I want to do is to show a Dialog with a couple of options that I designed in xml.
Here is how the code looks:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_main);

    Dialog_Choices(); 
}
public void Dialog_Choices()
{
     Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test_dialog);

     Button_FinishOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishOne);
    Button_FinishTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishTwo);
    Button_FinishThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishThree);

     dialog.setTitle("اختار عدد مرات");
     dialog.setCancelable(false);


    Button_FinishOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

The problem is that Button_FinishOne is null when it reaches SetOnClickListener..

If I change the SetContentView in the OnCreate to (R.layout.test_dialog) , it works.

R.layout.test_dialog has 3 buttons in a relativeView

R.layout.test_main has a listview.

How can I have a xml layout for the main Activity, and another xml for the dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using dialog.findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishOne) instead of just findViewById

Comment: Thanks for the (very) quick answer.

Comment: yea i just did.. you have to wait 10 mins before accepting an answer and you answered after only 1 minute :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 Button_FinishOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishOne);
 Button_FinishTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishTwo);
 Button_FinishThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishThree);
```

to

```
 Button_FinishOne=(Button)(dialog.findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishOne));
 Button_FinishTwo=(Button)(dialog.findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishTwo));
 Button_FinishThree=(Button)(dialog.findViewById(R.id.Ramadan_Button_FinishThree));
```